# rsyslog seems to be triggering sdhci dumps when writing in external storage

Tags: debian, kernel, rsyslog, debian-buster, journald

Acording what I read, rsyslog is usually used to process logs and send them to another locations, either local (external storage, specific partition, etc.) or remote (logging server, for example). However I'm trying to configure rsyslog to store the logs in an external storage device (SD card) but I'm having problems with the `sdhci` driver in the kernel. First you have here the [rsyslog configuration](https://jfernandz.me/%7Ewyre/rsyslog.conf).

As you can see logs are being stored in `/data/logs`, which is actually the SD card as [lsblk output](https://jfernandz.me/%7Ewyre/lsblk.txt) shows. Nevertheless, I can see a strange thing in the [dmesg](https://jfernandz.me/%7Ewyre/dmesg.log). Apparently the kernel is creating the node `/dev/mmcblk0` for external storage which is listed as `mmc0`:

```
jul 26 11:03:40 pabx2 kernel: mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDXC card at address 59b4
jul 26 11:03:40 pabx2 kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 SD    58.9 GiB 
jul 26 11:03:40 pabx2 kernel:  mmcblk0: p1
```

However the `sdhci` dumps are regarding `mmc1`! which is the internal storage, not the external one!

```
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000008 | Version:  0x00001002
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Argument:  0x0056c808 | Trn mode: 0x0000002b
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0001 | Host ctl: 0x0000003c
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000a | Blk gap:  0x00000080
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000207
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000006 | Int stat: 0x00000000
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff000b | Sig enab: 0x03ff000b
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Caps:      0x546ec881 | Caps_1:   0x00000805
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000193a | Max curr: 0x00000000
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000000c
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x0000000182ff6200
jul 26 11:50:18 pabx2 kernel: mmc1: sdhci: ============================================
```

Why do you think is this? What has the hardware interrupt for the internal storage device to do with the external storage? When these dumps are triggered the system (Debian 10 Buster) becomes extremely slow, to the point it's inoperative, out-of-use.

Thank you all.

Comment: M ight a [Kernel bug](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-mmc/patch/20181130150028.732896d8@xdu1-mobl/)

Comment: I've tried two versions, the 4.19 and 5.10 (in the backports) both have the same behavior.